# Tying Into Existing Gas Line Near Patio

Tags: gas, patio

I have a natural gas line entering the back of house for indoor fireplace one foot from my patio. I would like to buy a natural gas grill for the patio. Of course I would hire the work done, but first I would like to know if it is possible to tee into the existing line with a with a second shutoff and quick connect for the grill which would set one foot from the pipe.  The FP and grill would never be online at the same time. Thanks.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Probably! There's a union there and it looks like probably a bigger line than just the fireplace needs. If you can let us know the minimum line size for the FP and your proposed grill, and measure the line before it heads in to the reducer bushing you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll have to find papers on FP. Most grills I’ve found are rated at 32000 BTU.

Comment: The claim about simultaneous use is dubious and shouldn't be considered. A gas pipe system must be able to serve all devices connected to it. So, please revise with the actual pipe size(s), run lengths, bend counts, supply pressure (if available), etc. That's how the answer is derived.

Comment: Thanks for answers.  I spoke with a local gas plumber yesterday who is working up a couple of options for me.  I appreciate the feedback.